# Installing Rtools: error with space in path

Tags: r

I am trying to install Rtools however am encountering error:

```
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have tried downloading from http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/ and also installing from within an Rstudio project, both return the same error.

I recognise that this is because of a space in the path "C:\Program Files..."  however it is confusing this would throw an error, given that I can install packages normally.

Does anyone know how I can fix this error?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if it will solve all of your problems, but you can use `PROGRA~1` as an alias for `Program Files` on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by creating a separate folder without any spaces in the name. i.e

```
C:/Rprogramfiles/R...
```