# DT Shiny R - [input$tableId_rows_all, ] not working

Tags: r, shiny, dt

i am not able to display all filtered rows from datatable in a plot, and the function, which suppose to use all filtered rows -> `input$tabelle_rows_all`, uses the rows only on the current page! My DT version is 0.1, and i cannot update it to **github version**. I have tried many approaches, first via `devtools::install_github('rstudio/DT')` but i got an error

```
...--install-tests Der Befehl "C:\Program" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder konnte nicht gefunden werden. Error: Command failed (1)
```

than  i downloaded the development version (https://github.com/rstudio/DT/archive/master.tar.gz) and i used command

`install.packages("C:/Users/XX/Downloads/DT-master.tar.gz",lib="C:/Users/XX/Docu‌​ments/R/win-library/3.2")`.

However still i got error:

`Warning in install.packages : package ‘C:/Users/XX/Downloads/DT-master.tar.gz’ is not available (for R version 3.2.3)`...

This is very necessary and important option which i need for DT, is there anyway i could get it done?

Easy example of the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(ggplot2)

x <- as.numeric(1:1000000)
y <- as.numeric(1:1000000)
data <- data.frame(x,y)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(dataTableOutput('tableId'),
                 plotOutput('plot1')),
  server = function(input, output) {    
    output$tableId = renderDataTable({
      datatable(data, options = list(pageLength = 100, lengthMenu=c(100,200,300,400,500,600)))
    })
    output$plot1 = renderPlot({
      filtered_data <- data[input$tableId_rows_all, ]
      ggplot(data=filtered_data, aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_line()
    })
  }
)
```

Thanks for any interest

**[Just to clear it one more time]**:

I got quite big data (>5000000 rows), and i display it in shiny app using datatable (`DT`) with filters. Depending on the user preferences for filtering, lets assume it gives us 550 rows (but it can give us more or less than that). Because of pagination I am not able to see all 550 rows (assuming `pageLength` is 100) or whats even worse, **i am not able to display all filtered rows further in a plot**, as function `input$tabelle_rows_all` **uses the rows on the current page** (i must first change the entries number). **Is there any way to get all found rows after filtering datatable (not depended on** `pageLength`)?

I read somewhere that the problem might be with the version od `DT`, so maybe `DT` 0.1 does not support the function to plot all the found rows, so i am hoping that the github version of `DT` is the solution of my problem. But i might be wrong!

Comment: Got same Error: `Downloading GitHub repo rstudio/DT@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/rstudio/DT/zipball/master
Installing DT
Installing 1 package: htmlwidgets
package ‘htmlwidgets’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked "C:/Program Files/R/R-32~1.3/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore CMD INSTALL  \
  "C:/Users/XX/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpYHkDIK/devtools5104e037a5a/rstudio-DT-a63e9ac"  \
  --library="C:/Users/XX/Documents/R/win-library/3.2" --install-tests 
Der Befehl "C:\Program" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden`

Comment: ok looks like this [person had a similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22782537/error-after-running-build-to-create-r-package-in-rstudio), this [one as well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30125476/installing-rtools-error-with-space-in-path)... spaces in path

Comment: Hey, thanks for idea, i do not have admin rights, but as soon as team leader shows up i am going to try it:However the post below by Bas said DT is not available for R Version 3.2.3..?

Comment: Your code runs fine for me on R version 3.2.3, `DT` version 0.1, on Mac

Comment: @Malvina_a, I am not entirely sure if my answer works, it's what I think what will work. What NicE said could also be the case, but it also depends what kind of server you're running.

Comment: Hey everyone, i need **github version of** `DT`, version 0.1 i have installed on my RStudio. **Github version** i guess **allows me to use** `input$tableid_rows_all` . Version 0.1 of `DT` is not working with `input$tableid_rows_all` (so i cannot plot all the filtered data, i can plot  **only the data which is on the currently opened page of** `DT` ). I need to plot all the **filtered data from all pages**

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error you're getting I believe you have newer version of R (3.2.3) which is not yet supported by the DT package.

If you downgrade your R version to an older one it should work (it works fine for me on Version 3.1.2). [This article](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486138-Using-Different-Versions-of-R) might help you installing an old version of R if you are using Rstudio, or [this topic](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/How-to-install-older-version-of-R-td889239.html) if you are using R on ubuntu.

Once you install the old(er) version of R, you can install the package by typing:

```
install.packages("DT")
```

And then you should be able to load it by typing:

```
library(DT)
```

Comment: Hey Bas, is it sure that DT is not available for R (3.2.3)? I am not very convinced by the warning which i received at the beginning `Warning in install.packages : package ‘C:/Users/XX/Downloads/DT-master.tar.gz’ is not available (for R version 3.2.3)`. I just wanna be sure before actually going to the IT guys (I am not using R locally, its on our server)

Comment: @Malvina_a Have you tried the `install.packages("DT")` command? You may need sudo access before running R. Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33123370/unable-to-download-packages-from-r-3-2-2-in-linux-mint-17-1/33124280#33124280) if `install.packages("DT")` fails.